# Get attributes in view from inherited objet

Tags: jpa, jsf, inheritance

In one of my jsf view I'm displaying a list of users with some information like : CardId (child), Firstname (parent), Lastname (parent).

Only the attributes from the child class are displayed.

The class User contain the Firsname and Lastname and the child a new attribute cardId.

```
<h:selectOneMenu>   
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Looking into my pocket  ..." />                    
    <f:selectItems value="#{PresentationBean.getReaders()}" var="reader" itemLabel="#{reader.cardId} (#{reader.firstname}-#{reader.lastname})" itemValue="#{reader.cardId}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Child class

```
@Entity
public class Reader extends User {

    private int cardId;

    //some code

}
```

Parent class

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Entity
public abstract class User {

    private String firstname, lastname;
    //some code

}
```

As result my dropdown only display the CardId

The log also state that all the field are queried.

```
20:36:26,627 INFO  [stdout] (default task-26) Hibernate: select reader0_.email as email2_4_, reader0_.city as city3_4_, reader0_.street as street4_4_, reader0_.zipCode as zipCode5_4_, reader0_.firstname as firstnam6_4_, reader0_.lastname as lastname7_4_, reader0_.accountBalance as accountB8_4_, reader0_.cardId as cardId9_4_ from User reader0_ where reader0_.DTYPE='Reader'
```

Comment: They are private so not visible in a child class.  Try creating a unit test without jsf and just a sysout... does it work? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=entity+private+fields+in+abstract+class&t=fpas&ia=web

Comment: @Kukeltje Changing the parent attributes to protected and using the public getter `getFirstname()` dosen't help neiter.

Comment: Then I have no idea since I use that consttuct in more than one project and it works all the time.

Comment: Solutions belong in answers and not in edited questions. And this is a weird workaround since for me this normally works.

Comment: @Kukeltje  last time I did so, an "Admin" deleted my answer and edited my post

Comment: I cannot imagine that unless it was not  a real answer (content wise)

Comment: @Kukeltje check yourself... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315016/not-able-to-persist-entities?noredirect=1#comment99351199_56315016 last post with solution deleted.

Comment: I cannot see the 'deleted solution' only posters of the solution can see those, so I cannot make a statement/judgement.  Can you also please add your jpa version and implementation to the question? I removed the java-ee tag since it is too broad and replaced it with a jpa tag. And you still did not try in a plain non-jsf unittest